# CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync Gives null Exception Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to  Display Current Location on Map.For this I have Used  Geolocator  Plugin.I have Code for get current Location of Device.

```
[async void Maplaunch()
        {
            try
            {
                var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
                locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
                var pos = await locator.GetPositionAsync(10000);
                var approximateLocations = await geoCoder.GetPositionsForAddressAsync(TxtSerch.Text);
                var position = new Position(approximateLocations.First().Latitude, approximateLocations.First().Longitude);
                var possibleAddresses = await geoCoder.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(position);
                var pin = new Pin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(approximateLocations.First().Latitude, approximateLocations.First().Longitude),
                    Label = possibleAddresses.First().ToString(),
                    Address = possibleAddresses.First().ToString()
                };
                HomeMap.Pins.Add(pin);
                HomeMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(position, Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }]
```

but when I debug CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(10000) I get exception.please help me. Thanx in advance.
[Check Image of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbAsV.png)

Comment: Are you getting this error with both iOS and Android, or just one of them? Also can you post the stacktrace from the exception?

Comment: when  i reach  to await geoCoder.GetPositionsForAddressAsync(TxtSerch.Text); by Debug I go out of try Catch Block.i have added Permission For  Ios :<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Get Nearby Friend</string>
    <key>AllowsBackgroundUpdates</key>
    <string>True</string>

Comment: Sometimes the debugger doesn't like to step over awaits. Try setting a second breakpoint on the line after the await as well so that if the debugger is acting up you can still step through.